# Return a value on closing from a form without showdialog

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, showdialog, mdichild

I have a mdi application from which I want to call a mdi child form. This form has to return a value on closing to its parent. How can I manage that without using `ShowDialog()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `OnClosing` event of the child form and set a value of a variable of the parent form class before closing.

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form1.myVar = 3;
}
```